# How to get the latest time on each day given a collection of dates in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm setting up a service that takes EOD (end of day) values from a MongoDB collection every 4 days. Within this period, documents are created every 5 minutes, which means I would need to return the 4 EOD values after each period, or in other words, I need to get the latest time of each day given a collection of dates.

I'm running node 10 and using mongoose to interface with mongodb. I've tried googling this problem but it seems that mongodb doesn't provide an out of the box solution. I tried bruteforcing it by creating a hash to each time and taking the max time but this feels like it's too computationally intense

Here is an example of the time collection:

```
[ 'Sun Aug 02 2019 21:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)',
  'Sun Aug 02 2019 21:05:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)',
  'Sun Aug 03 2019 21:10:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)',
  'Sun Aug 03 2019 21:15:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)',
  'Sun Aug 04 2019 21:20:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)',
  'Sun Aug 04 2019 21:20:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)' ]
```

Given the list above, I need to return:

```
['Sun Aug 02 2019 21:05:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)',
 'Sun Aug 03 2019 21:15:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)',
 'Sun Aug 04 2019 21:20:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Note:- you simply can do it with node js. here is an example. or if you want to do it with MongoDB then you need to convert date to timestamp while saving the document in collection and you can get data in ascending/descending order as you want.

while saving the document, you need to add a timestamp

```
 {
   timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now},
 }
```

while retrieving the data from MongoDB collection, you need to add a timestamp.

```
ascendingOrder = {'timestamp': 1} //ascending order
descendingOrder = {'timestamp': -1} //descending order
collection.find({}, limit=20).sort(descendingOrder)
```

1 is for ascending order and -1 is for descending order. The default value is 1.

```js
var dates = [
  'Sun Aug 04 2019 21:20:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)',
  'Sun Aug 02 2019 21:05:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)',
  'Sun Aug 03 2019 21:10:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)',
  'Sun Aug 02 2019 21:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)',
  'Sun Aug 03 2019 21:15:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)',

  'Sun Aug 04 2019 21:20:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)'
]
var sortedDates = dates.sort(function(var1, var2) {
  var a = new Date(var1),
    b = new Date(var2);
  if (a > b)
    return 1;
  if (a < b)
    return -1;

  return 0;
});
console.log(sortedDates);
```

Comment: This is great! However, the second part of this is where I'm having trouble. I only want the single latest record for each day. The first part may be sorting the list, but is there a quick way to group by day?

Comment: Yes, in that case, you need to pass limit=1(to get single record). a quick way to get data from the collection. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/